# Designing an ER diagram for Hockey League Database

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

**Question:** Draw the ER diagram for the hockey league database for which the requirements are as follows:

*I am having problem in certain portion of the question, so I am including only that part.*

The League has many teams where each team has a name, a city, a coach and a captain. A game is played between two teams such as host-team and guest team and has a date and a score.

**Assumptions I made**

1. Game is a weak entity because `date, host, guest` together uniquely identify a row in Game table.
2. Many games can be played in a single day. But two teams can play only one match in a day.

Accordingly, my ER diagram is as 
[image]

where `2...2` means group of two participations at a time.
*The direction of arrow is in the direction of many to one relationship*.

(This notation may be wrong, as I concluded it from some already solved problems in the net...In case of football matches, each match should have atleast 3 referees) **Please correct me if I am wrong**.

But the solution is given as

[image]

Where they have used a self relationship.

I doubt that my second assumption(and a very valid one) doesn't hold here.

My question is that keeping in mind the above assumptions, whether my designing is correct or not? If not what are the mistakes here?

**If I am wrong then please point it out. A possible way to rectify the mistake would really help.**

Comment: There are many methods for doing & diagraming ER design. Tell us what yours is. (Eg give a textbook name, edition & section.) (When you find the method presentation, you can edit your post to follow the method instead of random output from random ones from the web.) When giving a relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. When initially designing/specifiying tables or queries, cardinalities, constraints & if-then-else turn out not to be very helpful.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)  Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PS It's good that you give specs & solutions for just what you need & relate it to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Play is a relation(ship)/association type whose relationship instances relate/associate 3 participant entity instances--a Game & 2 Teams. Lines are 1:1 with such participations by entity types in a relationship type. Your diagram wrongly has just one participation/line to Team.

A number, range or other cardinality annotation on a line says something (depending on your method) about permitted/valid combinations of entity instance/subrow participations over multiple relationship instances/rows of a relationship type/table. It doesn't address the number of participations by one entity type in each relationship instance, which is what a line documents.

There are typically multiple reasonable ways to precisely/formally define an informal specification. So a "solution" different from yours wouldn't make yours wrong. Roughly speaking, Game corresponds to the associative entity type associated with GAME & Play corresponds to GAME.

PS "2...2 means group of two participations at a time" is too vague to be of any use. Find the precise statement that a cardinality annotation in your method says about entities & relationships & tables. Find & follow *all* the exact rules for the method. Your problems are the sort that come from trying to follow some vague wrong rephrasings of specific technical terms & rules. Your method's rules will *tell* you to have 2 lines & certain labels & certain annotations, but you have to follow what they actually say.

PS "Accordingly" is a huge jump in reasoning. Typically on such questions I vote to close as "too broad" or "not clear" & comment for clarification:

> Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--you may find mistakes that make your question unnecessary & we don't know exactly what algorithm you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an algorithm allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your textbook. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

But with your post it seems clear that the main problem is that you didn't follow the rules for participations or cardinalities.

PS "*The direction of arrow is in the direction of many to one relationship.*" In diagrams with diamonds the diamonds are the relation(ship)s/associations & the lines don't have arrows & represent participations/FKs (foreign keys). You are confusing Chen original ER (Entity-Relationship) design & diagramming with pseudo-ER methods & diagramming that don't use diamonds & call FKs "relation(ship)s". (But an ER FK is associated with a certain relationship/table.) Follow a method.